# Xcode Transitioning from .xib to Storyboards

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I have a sample xcode project which I downloaded to test out this. It has 2 .xib files (each with their own view controller header and mains). I have added a storyboard and set the ViewControllers classes to game and ViewController (the names of the .xibs) and set the main storyboard to the storyboard in the summary, but whenever I run the app it just runs the .xibs. 
**How can I get it to run the storyboard instead of the .xibs?**
Is there a section in storyboards I need to change or is it in the code for each .xibs .h and .m?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in your App Delegate. Here is an example set up to run with XIBS or Storyboard depending on target conditions...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#ifdef FORMAT_XIB
    NSLog (@"XIB VERSION");
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    CVViewController* myViewController = nil;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        myViewController = [ [CVViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CVViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil ];
    } else {
        myViewController = [ [CVViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CVViewController_iPad" bundle:nil ];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = myViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
#else
    NSLog (@"STORYBOARD VERSION");
#endif
    return YES;
}
```

If you are running a Storyboard app, you don't need all that. Delete it so that the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method just reads:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Wow.. I'm really new to this, it's a bit overwhelming. This is what I have:- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
     
    return YES;
} Any idea what I need?

Comment: sorry I should have given a short reply. All I meant to say is, all that stuff in the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method needs to go - it is all for the benefit of Xib loading. So delete everything except `return YES;`  ... also, if you have more info to your question, you should edit your question (there's no problem with adding updates to it), rather than trying to squish it all into a comment...

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I copied all the content of the .xib into a new project with a storyboard and just copied my ViewController.h and .m files keeping the plain delegate files. It's working fine now, thanks again